# Selenium ChromeDriver System properties NullPointerException

Tags: java, maven, selenium, properties, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote a maven program using selenium and it works fine, now I'm trying to externalize properties, suddenly I can't initiate chromedriver. I get this NullPointerException, it seems like the driver is trying to find some property in system properties file.

Here is my code

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(AmazonVendor.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("application.properties"));
System.setProperties(properties);

ChromeDriverService chromeDriverService = new ChromeDriverService.Builder()
            .usingDriverExecutable(new File(System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver")))
            .usingAnyFreePort()
            .withEnvironment(ImmutableMap.of("DISPLAY",":99"))
            .build();

    try {
        chromeDriverService.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGERR.error(e);
    }


    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

here is my application.properties

```
webdriver.chrome.driver=/home/cheng/chromedriver
files.download.dir=/home/cheng/Downloads/
emails.create.dir=/home/cheng/amazon_automation/emails/
java.home=/api/java/jdk1.8.0_131/jre/
```

here is my error

```
[WARNING] 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:297)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:326)
at com.apioutsourcing.websiteautomation.AmazonVendor.newDriver(AmazonVendor.java:222)
at com.apioutsourcing.websiteautomation.AmazonVendor.startAutomation(AmazonVendor.java:250)
at com.apioutsourcing.websiteautomation.AmazonVendor.main(AmazonVendor.java:285)
... 6 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.openqa.selenium.Platform.extractFromSysProperty(Platform.java:245)
at org.openqa.selenium.Platform.extractFromSysProperty(Platform.java:232)
at org.openqa.selenium.Platform.getCurrent(Platform.java:200)
at org.openqa.selenium.net.PortProber.<clinit>(PortProber.java:41)
... 10 more
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you need to provide more information. For example provide extractFromSysProperty method implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, it seems like `System.setProperties(properties)` would let java ignore all default properties and only look for properties in application.properties file, so I just use `System.setProperty` to set them individually, so java would still know the properties of the environment